# How to check TinyScrollBar is initialized or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

I have a JS code like this below:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($('.scrollbar-y').length) {
        $('.scrollbar-y').tinyscrollbar_update('relative');
    }
    if ($('.scrollbar-x').length) {
        $('.scrollbar-x').tinyscrollbar_update('top');
    }
});
```

at `$('.scrollbar-y').tinyscrollbar_update('relative');` this line it's showing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

So How to check TinyScrollBar is initialized or not with **`.scrollbar-y`** div ?

If I write:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($('.scrollbar-y').length) {
        $('.scrollbar-y').tinyscrollbar();
        $('.scrollbar-y').tinyscrollbar_update('relative');
    }
    if ($('.scrollbar-x').length) {
        $('.scrollbar-x').tinyscrollbar();
        $('.scrollbar-x').tinyscrollbar_update('top');
    }
});
```

It's showing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined

Comment: Have you tinyscrollbar-ed it already? You can't update it if you haven't made it into a tiny scrollbar yet.

Comment: @DaveNewton please check the edited version.

Comment: Don't forget that a selector in jQuery can return zero, one or more elements. Especially if the selector is a class. Try to change your code by : `$('.scrollbar-y').each(function() { $(this).tinyscrollbar_update('relative'); });`

Comment: @Fefux yes but i want that if with ".scrollbar-y" div tinyscrollbar is initialized or associated then only then scrollbar update will called.